# How to get a wave on 50% of screen?

Tags: css, waveform

In CSS, I want to make a background with 50% of a color and 50% of another color but this color need to be terminated by a wave like that:

[image: That]

Actually I have that:

[image: That]

But it doesn't take 50% of screen.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #3f2982;
}

#wavebg {
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  bottom: 0;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/IJelEnu.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id='wavebg'></div>
```

How I can change it for take 50% of the screen?

Comment: Can you please add your HTML

Comment: `position: relative!important;` <-- You shouldn't need to do that (and using `!important` is a _code-smell_: there are almost always better alternatives)

Comment: `float: left;` <-- Don't do this for page layout elements.

Comment: @BeerusDev added

Comment: @Dai okey thanks ;)

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the code provided does not replicate the issue

Comment: This doesn't reproduce what you have pictured above.

Comment: @BeerusDev just wrong color lmao

Comment: @カメロン https://codepen.io/bagou4502/pen/OJOLBGL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
      background-color: #3f2982;
      
    }

    #dark-bg {
      width: 45%;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #27184f;
      float: left;
    }

    #wavebg {
      position: relative;
      content: "";
      bottom: 0;
      background: url(https://i.imgur.com/IJelEnu.png);
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100vh;
      float: left;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="bg-container">
    <div id="dark-bg"></div>
    <div id='wavebg'>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Since the width of your image is not sufficient to cover 50% of screen width, your background image looks as if its stuck in the left border of the browser.
The trick is to apply a div immediately left to the image with the same color as the image.
This will get you the desired result of wave in approximate center of the screen. You may need to adjust #dark-bg width with css @media queries for a better responsive layout.

I sincerely hope it helps. This is the result you can have:
[image: Background image at 50%]

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: #3f2982;
}

body,html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#wavebg {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/IJelEnu.png');
  background-size: 70% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 60%;
  height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<html><body><div id='wavebg'></div></body></html>
```

Comment: This not work i want to get somethings like first screen here wave are just ugly

Comment: @Bagou450 I edited. Of course wave in your picture is different from this `URL` placed in your code.